# I need help proving: if $f : A \rightarrow B$ is injective, and $A1 \subset A $ and $A2 \subset A$, then $f(A1 \cap A2) = f(A1) \cap f(A2)$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

This is what I attempted.

Proof: Injection by definition states that (∀x,y ∈ A)[f(x) = f(y) ⇒ x = y] ∀x,y $∈ \Bbb R$. Let us look at the left side, $f(A1 \cap A2)$. Then an arbitrary x ∈ A is contained in $f(A1 \cap A2) ⇒ x ∈ A1 \land x ∈ A2$. The right side shows $f(A1) \cap f(A2)$ ⇒ $\exists x ∈ A1 \land x ∈ A2$. So in both cases x is contained and since $f : A \rightarrow B$ is injective the x term must be the same number and $f(A1 \cap A2) = f(A1) \cap f(A2)$.

Now my solution is wrong, I'm not very good at containment proofs but I want to improof (get it? improve!). Some marks I got for feedback include for me to show containment both ways and to start x ∈ $f(A1 \cap A2) ⇒ ... ⇒ x ∈ f(A1) \cap f(A2)$, and vice versa. Any help is appreciated and sorry in advance for the poor formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one direction, you want to show $f(A_1\cap A_2)\subseteq f(A_1)\cap f(A_2)$. You start fine by choosing $x\in f(A_1\cap A_2)$ (although the $x$ you choose is in $B$, not in $A$, since it is in the image of $f$). Then $x\in f(A_1\cap A_2)$ implies that there is some $a\in A_1\cap A_2$ such that $f(a) = x$ (this is just the definition of $f(A_1\cap A_2)$. But since $a\in A_1\cap A_2$, then $a\in A_1$, so that $f(a)\in f(A_1)$. Similarly $f(a)\in f(A_2)$. Thus $f(a)\in f(A_1)\cap f(A_2)$, so that $f(A_1\cap A_2)\subseteq f(A_1)\cap f(A_2)$.

The other direction is different, but not hard once you understand how this direction works (note, though, that what I did above does not use the fact that $f$ is injective, so you will likely be needing that fact). The proof you gave simply is not clear or correct as regards where different objects live, or in terms of stating what you are trying to prove.

Comment: This helped me see why I wasn't going anywhere, thanks a lot! I think I might just be able to do the reverse direction. @rogerl

Comment: For the reverse way, I would start f(A1)∩f(A2)⊆f(A1∩A2) and let an x be in f(A1)∩f(A2) correct? @rogerl

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Alright let me see if I understand a little. Let $y \in f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$. This implies that there is a $b_1 \in A_1$, $b_2 \in A_2$ such that $f(b_1)=y$ and $f(b_2)=y$. But since $f(b_1)=f(b_2)$, this implies that $b_1=b_2$ because of the injectivity of the function. Am I on the right track or should I start all over? @rogerl

Comment: You are on the right track. In fact, you're almost done. Good work.